# Why does my ASPX app keep logging the user out?

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

This ASPX app I'm working on keeps logging me out mid-session. I tried changing this:

```
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="24" />
```

To

```
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="1440" />
```

But it still times out every couple of minutes (sometimes sooner). I've never programed in ASPX before and I'm just making basic layout changes (removing three nested tables, etc.), but it's horrible how many times I have to log in to do even the simplest things.

Any clue what else might be timing me out if not the session state? I didn't write any of this...

Comment: Please specify after what exactly time you been logged out. What other auth settings you have use.

Answer (score 0):

The InProc and the session is not keep the logging authentication. This authentication is done using some other cookie that if you loose it you logged out.

**There are two points to look** - if you move from `http` to `https` and if you move from `www.` to non `www.` pages.

To solve that go to your `web.config` and check if you have setup that properties correctly (especial the `domain`).

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="50" path="/" requireSSL="true" cookieless="UseCookies" domain="domain.com" />
</authentication>
```

Also check on `roleManager` and on `httpCookies` that you have setup the domain.